# Cassandra tunable consistency with multiple clients

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I've been watching the Datastax Cassandra tutorials, and I have a question about tunable consistency. The equation they show is `if (nodes_read + nodes_written) > replication_factor`, then we have immediate consistency. This only seems to be true if there is one client connecting to the DB. If we have multiple clients, I don't see how this equation can still hold. Is the assumption here that we only have one client? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is irrespective of the number of clients.

As long as you're reading and writing quorum, for example, you're guaranteed to be consistent. Remember that in Cassandra last write wins. So in other words, you're guaranteed not to read stale data.

#### Don't take this equation too far though

Rarely do I see configurations other than one one or quorum quorum. Things like write 1 read ALL are consistent in theory, but what's consistency worth if you're down?

Also make sure you run NTP.

Comment: "what's consistency worth if you're down?"  Plus one from me.  That's brilliant (and very true).

Answer (score 0):

The number of clients does not matter. The consistency is on the data not the client or the number of clients.

If there are 100 clients each performing the writes and reads based on (nodes_read + nodes_written) > replication_factor, then in that case you can still be pretty sure that all the clients will see immediate consistency.

Why do you think many clients will change the equation?

One of the reasons you will see immediate consistency is:

1. Writes are only successful after the writes to 'n' nodes are successful
2. Reads are only successful if 'n' nodes reply. The data that is returned is the data that is associated with the latest time stamp.

To clarify your comment about multiple nodes, lets consider two cases.

Case 1.
Lets say there are 3 nodes and the replication factor is 3

1. Lets say client 1 is writing data with CL = 2. This will make sure that write is successful only after write is successful on 2 nodes
2. Now if a client performs a read with CL=2, at least one of the written nodes will reply. Hence getting immediate consistency.

Case 2:

1. Lets say client is writing data with CL=1. This will make sure that only 1 write is successful.

Now the question comes into picture what if you perform a read on one of the nodes that don't have data.

2. To satisfy the formula you have to perform a read with CL=3. This means that reads are triggered with all 3 nodes. Now 3 nodes have to respond. One of the nodes has the data and the other 2 don't. The highest timestamp wins, hence node 1 wins. Hence the data is returned.

No stale data

Case 3: 
1. Lets say the write is performed with CL=3. In that case, we only get a successful when we have the data in 3 of the replica nodes.

Now the question comes into picture what if you perform a read on one of the nodes that don't have data. But as the CL was 3, all the nodes will have the data for a successful write

2. Read on any of the nodes **WILL** succeed.

Comment: Please correct my reasoning: There is a replication factor of three, and the consistency of writes is three, and the consistency of reads is one. That should give us consistent reads from the equation. Client 1 begins to write to 3 nodes, but while it is doing that, Client 2 reads data from one node that has not yet been written to. As the read consistency is 1, Client 2 returns stale data. Is my assumption that immediate consistency includes currently updating data wrong?

Comment: @worker1138 Please see Case 1 and Case 2 from my answer

Comment: thank for your answer. I agree that in the scenarios you have outlined the equation holds for immediate consistency. But I still am not convinced my scenario would not return stale data.

Comment: @worker1138 Why exactly is that? I am very sure that immediate consistency is guaranteed

Comment: I'm referring to the scenario I outlined in my comment.

Comment: Ah, but in my case the read CL is only, not three, as in your scenario. The write CL is three.

Comment: @worker1138, it doesn't matter the generic formulae holds good. I still don't understand your concerns, anyways added another Case to make it even more clear